# java.sql.SQLException: GSS-API authentication exception

Tags: angular, gradle, intellij-idea, mariadb

I created a SpringBoot project and work with Angular/MariaDB/Node.js/Gradle and a Docker.

In IntelliJ  tried to connect to the MariaDB - Database. Even though i use the right User/Password, there is following error:

```
DBMS: MariaDB (no ver.)
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=exact
[28000][1045] GSS-API authentication exception
Unable to obtain Principal Name for authentication.
```

Furthermore, starting the Application of the Backend, i receive following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: GSS-API authentication exception:


at org.mariadb.jdbc.plugin.authentication.addon.gssapi.StandardGssapiAuthentication.authenticate(StandardGssapiAuthentication.java:115) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.0.6.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.plugin.authentication.addon.SendGssApiAuthPacket.process(SendGssApiAuthPacket.java:79) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.0.6.jar:na]
..
```

and

```
t backend.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain Principal Name for authentication 
    at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForName(Krb5LoginModule.java:826) ~[jdk.security.auth:na]
    at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:689) ~[jdk.security.auth:na]
    at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:597) ~[jdk.security.auth:na]
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:679) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:677) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:677) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587) ~[na:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.plugin.authentication.addon.gssapi.StandardGssapiAuthentication.authenticate(StandardGssapiAuthentication.java:66) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.0.6.jar:na]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
```

I think I set up everything right. I use Java 17 and Gradle is in 7.6, which should be compatible as well, but can't seem to find the problem. Anyone knows any posibility to fix that?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour] and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76043737/unity-heidisql-connection-authentication-method-auth-gssapi-client-not-support . I guess you're not using the right password, and also you're running as "root". Create a dedicated user with password instead